# Creating Virtual Directory returns error

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

I wrote a web service and hosted it on Local IIS. I clicked Create Virtual Directory: Project URL (my local IP address is 192.168.1.102). I get an error:

```
Unable to create the virtual direcotry. Could not find the server 'http://192.168.1.102/ on the local mashine. Creating a virtual direcotry is only supported on the local IIS server.
```

What do I need to do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your request is quite a large request-  You have a few issues you need to overcome in order to successfully accomplish your task.

*The Problems:*

- Permissions
- Ensure *Site* is configured correctly within *IIS*.
- Ensure you've configured a valid *Application Pool* within *IIS*.

You see these are going to be your largest hurdles; mostly because in order for your site to function correctly it will have to allow the *Network Service* account to perform functionality-

Hopefully this starts to gauge your complexity a bit-

Without code it will be difficult to see why this error has occurred.  However, based on your listed *IP Address* that isn't your actual address.  You see your machine is connected to a *Router* which knows which machine made the given request-

Which means your real *IP* could be: `50.5.1.14` but the *Router* has assigned you an *IP* of `192.168.1.102`.  So you'd want to target your *Wide Area Network* and ensure that your *local machine* will accept the request when it goes through your port.

If your actually testing this on a *local machine*, the most simplistic thing you could do would be to use the `localhost` address-  This will utilize the *Network Interface Cards* built in *loopback address* `127.0.0.1`.  Which may alleviate your issue within your test environment.

Without more detail it will be quite difficult to correctly answer you.

Comment: I think that I have problem with IIS Service. If I re-installed my IIS local server, run again and in my browser go http://localhost, I get error:

Not Found
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Comment: You still have to make sure that any request, are bound to your default application pool and default site to utilize the localhost.